# FBChat and python can't send a simple message

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to send myself a message with fbchat and every time I do I get error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 12, in
>
> client.send(Message(text=msg, thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER))
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thread_id'

And I'm about to pull my hair out. I'm getting ThreadType from fbchat documentation and cant get around this error.

My code looks like this:

```
from fbchat import Client

from fbchat.models import *

client = Client(my_user, my_pass)

name = "christopher.batey"

friends = client.searchForUsers(name)

friend = friends[0]

uid = friend.uid

msg = "This is a test"

sent = client.send(msg, thread_id=uid, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
```

Comment: `from fbchat.models import *`

Comment: @OlvinRoght now I get error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thread_id'

Comment: @ChristopherBatey please add the new error traceback along with the rest of your code. From the looks of it `send` doesn't take a `thread_type`. Please make sure to post ALL relevant code to make a complete minimal and verifiable example. (Including imports).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse sorry for that. Here is all of it: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>

    client.send(Message(text=msg, thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER))

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thread_id'

Comment: @ChristopherBatey put it in the question not the comments.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse my imports are from fbchat import Client as well as from fbchat.models import *

Comment: The post has been edited and updated

Answer (score 1):

From your error code, I'm assuming your code is actually this:

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *

client = Client(my_user, my_pass)

name = "christopher.batey"

friends = client.searchForUsers(name)
friend = friends[0]
uid = friend.uid

msg = "This is a test"

sent = client.send(Message(text=msg, thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER))
```

The last part looks like it's putting the `thread_id` and `thread_type` arguments inside of the Message class, when they're actually arguments for the `client.send()` function. It should look like this instead:

```
sent = client.send(Message(text=msg), thread_id="christopher.batey", thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
```

Hope that answers your question!